# controlling objects in another class

Tags: java, swing

I am learning Java, and am unsure what I am doing wrong.
What I am trying to develop is a swing application with a number of different panels.

Depending on what is done in what has happened in one panel, I need to be able to change the status of components in other panels.

Have tried a number of things but as of yet have been unable to changes in the second panel.

Have enclosed a small app that hopefully shows what I am trying to achieve.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;

public class MainApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new MainApp();
    }

    public MainApp() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Sample App");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });

    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {
        public TestPane() {
            setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 2));
            add(createLeftPane());
            add(new JPanel());
        }

        private JPanel createLeftPane() {
            JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
            panel.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(10, 10, 10, 10));

            JPanel content = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
            content.setOpaque(false);

            JPanel top = new PanelOne().createPane();
            JPanel bottom = new PanelTwo().createPane();

            content.add(top, BorderLayout.NORTH);
            content.add(bottom, BorderLayout.CENTER);

            panel.add(content);
            return panel;
        }
    }

    public class PanelOne extends JPanel implements ActionListener{
        public JButton btnOne = new JButton("one");
        public JButton btnThree = new JButton("three");

        protected JPanel createPane() {
            btnOne.addActionListener(this);
            btnThree.setEnabled(false);
            JPanel top = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
            top.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.gray, 1));
            top.add(new JLabel(" One"), BorderLayout.NORTH);
            top.add(btnOne, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
            top.add(btnThree, BorderLayout.CENTER);
            return top;
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            btnThree.setEnabled(!btnThree.isEnabled());
            // TODO Change btnTwo setting it enabled.
            //          PanelTwo.this.btnTwo.setEnabled(true);
        }   
    }

    public class PanelTwo extends JPanel implements ActionListener{
        public JButton btnTwo = new JButton("two");

        protected JPanel createPane() {
            btnTwo.setEnabled(false);
            btnTwo.addActionListener(this);
            JPanel top = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
            top.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.gray, 1));
            top.add(new JLabel(" Two"), BorderLayout.NORTH);
            top.add(btnTwo, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
            return top;
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            // TODO 
            // 1) disable btnOne and btnThree           
        }   
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In trying to control access to objects in a different class, you must be able to use the object in the part of your program that you are using, such as using the PanelTwo object to switch it's button off.

While you have made an effort to reduce the amount of code reuse, I think that you have not left access to your objects within the program.

In order to do this sort of thing you must start with

1.Constructors for the Panels One and Two, instead of createPane. Much simpler.

2.Getters and Setters for the private variables, Data Encapsulation.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_%28object-oriented_programming%29

http://www.beingjavaguys.com/2013/10/encapsulation-in-java.html

http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/java-ent/jnut/ch03_05.htm

What you were trying to do is access the class object, but since the variable was not static, the class object would just create a new object that is empty and doesn't contain the information that you put in your methods.
By chaining the access methods together you can follow the flow of the information and change it when you want and not rely on static variables that may or may not give you the results that you need.

Also, I think that after you have done all that you will need to figure out how the data encapsulation will work with your program. It might be a bit harder since you have a couple extra layers of classes and methods.

Once you have these added to the design of your program then you can access all of the objects you want. You don't want to allow access to your buttons from outside so use private and not public.

While the technical term for data encapsulating is restricting access, you can find that while you are restricting access you are opening up access available for the rest of your program where you want it.

This shouldn't take too long but will aid in you being able to access the panes button, as well as give you a good exercise to help in your learning.

Good Luck!